# Embedded calendar with Materialize

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, materialize

Is there a way to embed the Materialize Calendar into the page? I know you can put a datepicker input and show the calendar when you click on it, but I want to show the calendar as soon as the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

JS:

```
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
today: 'Today',
clear: 'Clear',
close: 'Ok',
closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
});
```

[Materialize Link Here](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to show only the calendar without clicking the text input.

Comment: Just add  $('.datepicker').click(); after the above code.